# Biofilm microtiter experimental design

Tags: biofilms

We sequenced RNA using RNA-seq from biofilm (attached to bottom) and planktonic growing bacteria (supernatant) in 3 mL microtiter plates.

I'm not sure how is possible to obtain planktonic cells since they may have precipitated. For bacteria growing on the bottom I'm convinced these were derived from initial attached cells and then formed biofilms growing anaerobically (this is a facultative bacteria). However, since this bacteria is not motile, how is possible I obtained planktonic bacterial cells RNA? Maybe was a suttle layer on the surface growing aerobically. Wouldn't them have precipitated after the 36h of the assay?

Specie: Haemophilus parasuis. A facultative anaerobe.